# Evaluating macros in answers package

Tags: answers

I am using the `answers` package to create a list of exercises in a set of lecture notes and solutions to those exercises as files separate from the notes.  I would like for the solution files to have the text of the corresponding question.  I tried storing the text of the exercise and then presenting it in the solution, but it doesn't get filled in.  For example,

```
\begin{exercise}
  \def\problemtext{
    Prove Proposition~\ref{prop:solnspan}.
  }
  \problemtext
  \begin{solution}
    \problemtext \\

    \textbf{Solution}\\
    (Solution goes here...)
  \end{solution}
\end{exercise}
```

The corresponding .tex file for the solutions though literally contains `\problemtext`, not filled in with the corresponding text.  This creates a bit of a problem since I build this TeX file separately from the notes.

Comment: How about a complete, minimal example that replicates your setup, rather than some code snippet?

Comment: Using the `\Opensolutionfile` and `\Closesolutionfile` macros this will work if `\gdef\problemtext` is used, but this is no good strategy, since it requires a new macroname for each `problem text`

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` -- since the counters are not the same, there must be two macros for retrieving the problemtext (or a more or less sophisticated `\let...` statement depending on which environment is active at the moment!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storeproblemtext}[1]{%
  \global\@namedef{problemtext\theexercise}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\retrieveproblemtext}{%
  \@nameuse{problemtext\theexercise}%
}

\newcommand{\solutionproblemtext}{%
  \@nameuse{problemtext\theSolution}% Counter is named Solution
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]

\begin{exercise}\label{prop:solnspan}
  \storeproblemtext{%
    Prove Proposition~\ref{prop:solnspan}.%
  }
  \retrieveproblemtext{1}%
  \begin{sol}
    Some text just for testing here:

    \solutionproblemtext%    

    \textbf{Solution}\\
    (Solution goes here...)
  \end{sol}
\end{exercise}


\begin{exercise}\label{einstein}
  \storeproblemtext{%
    Prove $E=mc^2$.%
  }

  \retrieveproblemtext%
  \begin{sol}
    Some text just for testing here:

    \solutionproblemtext%

    \textbf{Solution}\\
    (Solution goes here...)
  \end{sol}
\end{exercise}


\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** (Thanks to the suggestion of touhami!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storeproblemtext}[1]{%
  \global\@namedef{problemtext\@currentlabel}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\retrieveproblemtext}{%
  \@nameuse{problemtext\@currentlabel}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]

\begin{exercise}\label{prop:solnspan}
  \storeproblemtext{%
    Prove Proposition~\ref{prop:solnspan}.%
  }
  \retrieveproblemtext{1}%
  \begin{sol}
    Some text just for testing here:

    \retrieveproblemtext%    

    \textbf{Solution}\\
    (Solution goes here...)
  \end{sol}
\end{exercise}


\begin{exercise}\label{einstein}
  \storeproblemtext{%
    Prove $E=mc^2$.%
  }

  \retrieveproblemtext%
  \begin{sol}
    Some text just for testing here:

    \retrieveproblemtext%

    \textbf{Solution}\\
    (Solution goes here...)
  \end{sol}
\end{exercise}


\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you really want to use one command you can use `\Currentlabel` or the internal `\@currentlabel`

Comment: @touhami:I thought, this would not work because the Solution counter is only stepped and not refstepped, but this was an error! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This is still doing the same thing as before.  The TeX file that's generated for the solutions just says "\retrieveproblemtext" instead of the text of the problem.

Comment: @cjohnson: Yes, but the situation is still better than before, you have at least now the text in the solution which was not the case in your -- er -- non - document ;-)  I've not looked into `answers.sty`, but I assume that the solution stuff is just written verbatim to file, so hoping for expansion of macros is useless, in my point of view